# reversing a string of integers user enters (C)

Tags: c, string, reverse

What I want to do is reverse a string of numbers that the user enters. what happens is it compiles and runs till i hit enter after the  `scanf`. then I get some Microsoft runtime error... what's going wrong???

NOTE: this is homework, but i've got the logic figured out. what baffles me is this error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    unsigned int giveStr = 0;
    char* charIt;
    printf("Enter a number to be reversed.\t");
    scanf("%d", &giveStr);
    fflush(stdin);
    sprintf(charIt, "%d", giveStr);
    revStr(giveStr);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

revStr(unsigned int n)
{
      char buffer[100];
      int uselessvar, counter = 0;
      for (; n > 0;)
      {
           uselessvar = sprintf(&buffer[counter], "%d", n);
           counter++;
      }
      for (counter = 0; counter > 0;)
      {
          printf("%c", buffer[counter]);
          counter--;
      }
      return 0;
}
```

EDIT: flushing stdin for newlines :/ and also image [here](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/pictures/winerror.jpg) just not with that program. with mine.

Comment: You should paste the actual error you get.  I don't know anything about Windows but I'm kind of surprised you're flushing stdin.

Comment: flushing for newlines -> they're a bitch with scanf

Comment: Just so you know, the proper format string for an `unsigned int` is `"%u"`, not `"%d"`.  Although it wouldn't really contribute to the error, you should fix it.

Comment: @tekkno: Both answers so far solve part of the reason why it crashes for you.  You should apply those fixes first, see how it goes and report back.  Sure we can fix it for you completely but you won't learn from that.  I'm more than willing to help but I want to give you the chance to find out how to resolve it given the hints so far.

Comment: Why all this sprintf-ing? The most sormal solution would be sort of 1)create a buffer to store the string 2)Read string into the buffer with scanf 3)Pass it to a `void rev(char*)` function that reverses the array in-place 4)Print the result with printf("%s")

Comment: **Never** call `fflush(stdin)` - the result is undefined. See http://linux.die.net/man/3/fflush

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your home work problem, if you have the [K&R book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28programming_language%29), turn to section 3.5 and read it thoroughly.

Note the functions `reverse()` and `itoa()`. They should give you a pretty good idea on how to solve your problem.

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to access memory which is not allocated in:

```
 sprintf(charIt, "%d", giveStr);
```

Change  `char* charIt;` to `char charIt[50];` and all should be well (well, at least the segmentation fault part)

Also... pass `charIt` to `revStr`, as `charIt` contains the string with our number.
Then, a simple for loop in `revStr` will do the trick (what was the purpose of the second one, anyway?)

```
void revStr(char *giveStr)
{
  int counter;
  for (counter = strlen(giveStr)-1; counter >= 0; counter--)
  {
    printf("%c", giveStr[counter]);
  }
  printf("\n");
}
```

This will print each char our char representation has from the last one till the first one. You should read more on `for` loops.

Comment: revStr is supposed to receive a char or char array as an argument -> how do i implement this for an INT arrangement?

Comment: The way you do in main - use sscanf to convert the given int to a char array

Answer (score 1):

How does your program get out of the for (; n > 0;) loop?  Won't counter simply increase until you get a bus error?

ED:

Respectfully, I think the claim that "i've got the logic figured out" is a little optimistic. :^)  Doubtless someone will post the way it should have been done 
by the time I'm done writing this, but it's probably worth drawing attention to what went wrong (aside from the memory allocation problems noted elsewhere):

Your first loop, "for (; n > 0;)", is strange because you're printing the entire number n into the buffer at counter.  So why would you need to do this more than once?  If you were selecting individual digits you might, but you're not, and obviously you know how to do this because you already used "sprintf(charIt, "%d", giveStr);".  [Aside: giveStr isn't a great name for an unsigned integer variable!]

Your second loop also has strange conditions: you set counter to 0, set the condition that counter > 0, and then decrease counter inside.  This obviously isn't going to loop over the characters in the way you want.  Assuming you thought the first loop was character-by-character, then maybe you were thinking to loop down from counter-1 to 0?